# Converting Swift array to Couchbase lite ArrayObject

Tags: swift, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm trying to write a Swift string array, `[String]`, to a Couchbase lite 2.7 document. `MutableDocument` has a method `setArray(value: ArrayObject?, forKey: String)`. How can I convert the swift array to an ArrayObject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayObject` has a mutable counterpart `MutableArrayObject` that has an initialiser that takes an `Array<Any>?`. Here's an example:

```
let swiftArray = ["foo", "bar"]
let CBLArray = MutableArrayObject.init(data: swiftArray)
print(CBLArray.toArray())
```